# Четыре вопроса к одному предложению

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, согласование, как, единственное-множественное-число

*Интуиция, а может, и предрассудки, от которых никто из нас не свободен, нарисовала в моем воображении образ судьи-энтузиаста, из тех, **что**, несмотря на многолетнюю службу, **продолжают** относиться к Закону(?) как к пылающему факелу, всегда готовому высветить истину.*
**[Не зови меня больше в Рим](https://books.google.ee/books?id=WmnHCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT24&lpg=PT24&dq=%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F,%20%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82,%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8,%20%D0%BE%D1%82&source=bl&ots=Rf3fTi6d82&sig=aFVGR0o7ICAEty3o5WeMS-OUYgY&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje6oaL8bPTAhUECiwKHbsmC6sQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BE%D1%82&f=false)**

- правильна ли запятая после "судьи-энтузиаста"?
- **что** или кто?
- **продолжают** или продолжает?
- нужна ли запятая после "к Закону"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Запятая нужна, поскольку далее приводится *уточнение*, что именно понимается автором под введённым им понятием "судья-энтузиаст", а не указание на принадлежность данного судьи-энтузиаста к конкретной группе судей-энтузиастов (судья-энтузиаст из тех, что с энтузиазмом строят нам козни второй месяц).
2. Здесь  "**тех, что**" употреблено обоснованно, в значении "**таких, которые**..."
3. Множественное число "продолжа**ют**" - в соответствии с числом употреблённого здесь "**тех**, что (= таких, котор**ые**"). В сочетании с "тех, кто" (ссылка на группу людей, которая здесь не вполне подходит) было бы возможно единственное число: "тех, **кто** (= каждый из которых) продолжа**ет**".
4. Запятой перед "как" здесь нет по причине смыслового единства группы сказуемого (*относиться как к факелу*; в сети популярен похожий учебный пример: "*держалась как хозяйка*") - глагол "относиться" здесь не имеет *самостоятельного* смысла, в отличие от такого примера: "*Вопросы прав работников относятся к Закону о труде, как уже отмечалось на прошлой лекции, а не к Уголовному кодексу*".